# Decide what fields to include for RelatedFields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have extended `User` with for example `MyUser`.

Then I have an `Item`, with a `ForeignKey` to `MyUser`.

In my serializer, I've added this:

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    items = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='item-detail', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = (...., 'items')
```

How can I decide what fields are included from the items, now it defaults to only the U

```
    ....
    "url": "http://192.168.0.110:8000/users/2/",
    "items": [
        "http://192.168.0.110:8000/items/1/",
        "http://192.168.0.110:8000/items/2/"
    ]
```

Let's say I want to include the name of the item instead and some other fields?

Comment: Have a look at [Nested Relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) in django rest framework.

Comment: Well, I did look there. But now that you say it, I should probably just change from HyperLinkRelatedField to the serializer for items instead.. Seems kinda logical...

Comment: It indeed is because you just don't want a url which points to that resource, you want the particular field details. However, if you also want the url you could include it just like you did for `MyUser` by extending `serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer`.

Comment: Feel free to add an anwer if you want, else  answer it myself

Comment: I added my comments in answer with some code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is [Nested Relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships). For that you would need to write a new serializer for `Item` model and include it in the `MyUserSerializer`:

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    items = serializers.ItemSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = (...., 'items', ...)


class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ....

    class Meta:
         model = Item
         fields = (....) # your fields
```

If you also need the `url` for items just as in `MyUserSerializer`, you can extend the other `ItemSerializer` with `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`.